# how to multiple where with array?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a $data variable, its contents are in the form of an array like this

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => 1
  3 => 4
]
```

and I want to find data like this

```
Model::where('id', $array)->get();
```

in such a way does not work, then how?
maybe you guys have a solution. thanks

Comment: use `whereIn` https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

Comment: data still does not appear, because there is an index. if the data array is like this it works
`
[1,4]
`

Answer (score 1):

You need to transform your array first:

```php
$arr = [
  0 => 1,
  3 => 4,
];

$indexes = array_values($arr);

Model::whereIn('id', $indexes)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Model::whereIn('id', $array)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use find() method it accepts single id or array of ids.
so you can do like this :

```
Model::find($array);
```

may it helps you...